# Better way to concatenate a sequence of string replacements in Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a concatenation of string replacements in this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION norm(t text) RETURNS text AS $$
        declare t1 text;
        declare t2 text;
        ...
        declare t10 text;
        BEGIN
            select replace (lower(t), ',', ' ') into t1;
            select regexp_replace (t1, '[^0-9a-z\s-]', '', 'g') into t2;
            ...
            select regexp_replace (t10, 'n?oise?.*', '', 'g') into t10;
            RETURN trim(t10);
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

At the moment it has 10 different operations and the number keeps on grow. Also it has the inconvenient that changing position to transformations forces to rename variables.

Is there a better way to manage this situation?

Comment: What does 10 different operations mean? on 10 different strings? Are all of your "replacements" just things you're getting rid of? or are some of them legit replacements?

Comment: Some are "rid of", others simple replacements. I am cleaning some addresses with lots of irregularities.

Comment: Depending on how many you have and how long they are, you may consider compiling them into a single regex and doing it one pass with pl/perl

Comment: Actually some "look ahead" in the regex can help and perl regex supports it. I didn't know I could use pl/perl dialect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help yourself by having a `replacements` table:

```
CREATE TABLE replacements
(
    execution_order INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    search_regexp TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (search_regexp > ''),
    replace_by TEXT NOT NULL,
    flags TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'g'
) ;
```

That you would populate with as many replacements you need to perform:

```
INSERT INTO replacements
    (execution_order, search_regexp, replace_by, flags)
VALUES
    (100, '[^0-9a-z\s-]', '', 'g'),
    (200, 'n?oise?.*', '', 'g') ;
```

And then change your function to use it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION norm(t_in text) 
RETURNS text AS 

$body$
DECLARE
    t_out text ;
    rep record ;
BEGIN
    t_out := replace(lower(t_in), ',', ' ') ;
    FOR rep IN
        SELECT search_regexp, replace_by, flags
        FROM replacements
        ORDER BY execution_order
    LOOP
        t_out := regexp_replace(t_out, rep.search_regexp, rep.replace_by, rep.flags) ;
    END LOOP ;
    RETURN t_out ;
END ;
$body$ 

LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT ;
```

And check the results:

```
SELECT
    norm('You don''t like diacriticals àèìòùáéíóú') AS n1,
    norm('You do like noiseless numbers') AS n2,
    norm('And whatever you like to try also, removing commas, , , ') AS n3;
```

```
n1                          | n2           | n3                                                      
:-------------------------- | :----------- | :-------------------------------------------------------
you dont like diacriticals  | you do like  | and whatever you like to try also  removing commas
```

This won't be as fast as hard-coding all the changes in your function, but will allow for highest flexibility.

---

As an alternative, you can just change the code structure of your function, and *reuse* the same variable more than once<sup>1</sup>:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION norm(t_in text) 
RETURNS text AS 

$body$
DECLARE
    t_out text ;
BEGIN
    t_out := replace(lower(t_in), ',', ' ') ;
    t_out := regexp_replace(t_out, '[^0-9a-z\s-]', '', 'g') ;
    t_out := regexp_replace(t_out, 'n?oise?.*', '', 'g') ;
    -- Keep adding substitutions, or inserting them where appropriate
    RETURN t_out ;
END ;
$body$ 

LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT ;
```

This is faster, and the best alternative if the number of substitutions is moderate.

You can check it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=548e9d55ecf0df1684b34f62cb9f4c85)*

---

<sup>1)</sup> PLPGSQL is not a functional language that forces you to assign only once to `val`s, variables can be overwritten as many times as necessary. If you think in [Scala](https://sanaulla.info/2009/07/02/val-versus-var-in-scala-2/) terms, they're `var`s, not `val`s. In Java terms, they aren't `immutable`.

Answer (score 2):

## With `plperlu` and `Regexp::Assemble`

It depends on the length of the string and the length of the input. You can create a fully optimized regexp, using [Perl's Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) and run it with plperlu.

The below code caches the regex for the entire session, so subsequent calls should be stupid fast.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_from_all(text, text[])
RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
  use strict;

  my ( $text, $rearray ) = @_;
  my $re;

  my $allre = join '', @$rearray;
  if ( exists $_SHARED{$allre} ) {
    $re = $_SHARED{$allre};
  }
  else {
    require "Regexp/Assemble.pm";
    my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
    $ra->add($_) for @$rearray;
    $re = $_SHARED{$allre} = $ra->re;
  }

  $text =~ s/$re//ge;
  return $text;
$$
LANGUAGE plperlu
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now you can call it with,

```
SELECT replace_from_all('foobar', ARRAY['o', 'b'] );
```

Alternatively, you hard core the regexes in there, but if you're going to do that you may as well chop out `Regexp::Assemble`, and just paste a precompiled regex.

## With `plperl`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_from_all(text, text[])
RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
  use strict;

  my ( $text, $rearray ) = @_;
  my $regexes;

  my $allre = join '', @$rearray;
  if ( exists $_SHARED{$allre} ) {
    $regexes = $_SHARED{$allre};
  }
  else {
    $regexes = $_SHARED{$allre} = [map qr/$_/, @$rearray];
  }

  foreach my $re ( @$regexes ) {
    $text =~ s/$re//ge;
  }
  return $text;
$$
LANGUAGE plperl
IMMUTABLE;
```

### Speed

For this example I took the following sample data which is 300,000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT t.x FROM generate_series(1,1e5)
  CROSS JOIN ( VALUES
    ('You don''t like diacriticals àèìòùáéíóú'),
    ('You do like noiseless numbers'),
    ('And whatever you like to try also, removing commas, , , ')
) AS t(x);
```

For comparison, the above version by @joanolo takes 8.04 seconds

```
SELECT norm(x) FROM foo;
```

Using plperl with,

```
SELECT replace_from_all(x, ARRAY['[^0-9a-z\s-]', 'n?oise?.*'])
FROM foo;
```

It takes 5.0 seconds.

Comment: I really like your solution. Locally works nicely for me, but I have this problem now: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179944/installing-a-language-with-postgres-on-rds

Comment: @Randomize RDS isn't PostgreSQL.

Comment: it is not probably a "clean" PostgreSQL instance. What I am running at the moment is https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/

Comment: @EvanCarroll: **Why the *amazon-rds* flag only?** This is a valid question for PostgreSQL in general. And *amazon-rds* could also be well *mysql*. I think the question should be flagged with just *postgresql*, and its body be edited to include the fact that the user is limited to using only the *extensions* already provided by Amazon RDS PostgreSQL.

Comment: I totally didn't realize Amazon-RDS was anything but a forked version of PostgreSQL

Comment: @Randomize see the update