# Installing a language with Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, perl

I am using an instance of Postgres on RDS and I am trying to run:

`=> create language plperlu;`

but I get:

`ERROR:  must be superuser to create procedural language "plperlu"`

If I run:

```
=> grant rds_superuser to treex;
NOTICE:  role "treex" is already a member of role "rds_superuser"
GRANT ROLE
```

Is it actually possible to use perl extensions for Postgres on RDS or the only solution is creating a Docker instance with Postgres and Perl modules preinstalled?

Comment: RDS has some languages already installed, but I doubt they will allow the *untrusted* version of PERL. This could compromise their systems. So, you'll have to install PostgreSQL on you own (virtual) machine (or Docker).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this on RDS. The `rds_superuser` isn't a true superuser and cannot load any C-language extensions.

Comment: We should be cataloging every question tagged PostgreSQL that should be RDS.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I usually remember to add the rds tag, please do so too

Answer (score 1):

RDS has some languages already installed, but they do not allow you to install any package which isn't already there.

From the [RDS documentation on Extensions for PostgreSQL 9.6](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.96x):

> The following table shows PostgreSQL extensions for PostgreSQL version 9.6.x that are **currently supported by PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS**. "N/A" indicates that the extension is not available for that PostgreSQL version. [...]
>
> ```
> [...]
> plls      1.5.3   
> plperl    1.0       
> plpgsql
> [...]
> postgres_fdw
> [...]
> ```

PLPERLu is not in the  list.

**They won't let you install the *untrusted* version of PERL. This could compromise their systems.**

---

**(Untested) workaround**

So, if you really need this feature, you'll have to install PostgreSQL on you own (virtual) machine (or Docker), and use it there.

You can profit from PLPERLu in your box *from* RDS via some trickery with `PostgreSQL FDW` and triggers

1. Setup your *main* (constrained) database at RDS.
2. Setup your *aux* (unconstrained) database at your own box...
3. Link the two together using `postgres_fdw` from *main* to *aux*.
4. You *cannot* call directly a function via FDW. But you can have one table with an `INSERT or UPDATE TRIGGER` that performs the function call you're interested. This table could have a structure `(parameter1, parameter2, ... , parameterN, result)`, and the trigger could be fired when you `INSERT or UPDATE`, to generate the column `new.result`.

---

NOTES:

1. I've never tried this.
2. I don't know which connectivity restrictions does RDS put to `postgres_fdw` or other data wrappers. They *may* restrict which are the permitted connection IP addresses, and this might make RDS unable to reach your *aux* database.